# Repeating Image Background in Table Cell

Tags: tables, graphics, backgrounds, cell

I want to create a table with a cell that has a repeating image as a background, i.e. the image should not stretch to fill the entire cell, but rather tile (like in the example below).

I have the image as a vector (pdf); if it were possible to use the vector original that would be a bonus.

[image: Table with repeating image background]
[image: Example image that repeats in the cell's background]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

One out of many options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={scale=0.25,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt]{
 \includegraphics{example-image-a} & \includegraphics{example-image-b} &\includegraphics{example-image-c}\\ 
 \includegraphics{example-image-b} & \includegraphics{example-image-c} &\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\ 
 \includegraphics{example-image-c} & \includegraphics{example-image-a} &\includegraphics{example-image-b}\\ 
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]